# TKinter : get variable in Python class and send it to another

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to send one variable from one class to other.

My code:

The class I get variable

```
class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #TOOLBAR MENU
        toolbar = tk.Frame(self, bd = 1, relief = tk.RAISED)

        self.choicebutton = tk.Button(toolbar, command=self.choice)

        #TOOLBAR MENU
        toolbar = tk.Frame(self, bd = 1, relief = tk.RAISED)
```

The class I import variable :

```
class Frame1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        

        a.Application.choicebutton.config(state="disabled")
```

I got error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Application' has no attribute 'choicebutton'
```

Comment: You need to use the instance of `Application` to access `choicebutton`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `parent` is the `Application` object:

```
class Frame1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        parent.choicebutton.config(state="disabled")
```

Answer (score 0):

change the last line into to

```
a.Application().choicebutton.config(state="disabled")
```

Comment: Thats' *a* fix; it's unclear whether creating a new instance of `Application` is the right thing to do, though. More likely, the instance of `Frame` is probably supposed to be associated with an existing instance.

Comment: What the point of creating a new instance of `Application` to just setting a checkbutton to disable state because the instance cannot be used later (as it is not assigned to a variable)?

Comment: it is just a quick solution without changing much of the code. nothing else. there is no need to create a new instance.